# Hide all buttons in HTML without using ID and Class using Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML format looks like this :

```
<body>
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td><span><input type="button"/></span></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>

    <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td><span><input type="button"/></span></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

I want to hide all buttons without using class and ID. I've tried everything to hide the buttons but its not working.

What I've tried is something like this :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

and

```
input_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (element in input_list) {
 element.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will make u sense with javascript

```js
var i =document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for( var n in i){
    if(i[n].type = "button"){ 
      alert("hide button "+n);    
      i[n].style.visibility = "hidden";    
      }
}
```

```html
<body>
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td><span><input type="button"/></span></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>

    <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td><span><input type="button"/></span></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to hide all buttons in your form use

```
       $("input[type^=button]").each(function (index) {
         $(this).hide();
        });
```

UPDATE: may be this could help you

```
        var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        if (ele.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
                if (ele[i].type == "button")
                    ele[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

Comment: its working. But i need it in javascript not in Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to hide all buttons

Just use

```
$('input').hide();
```

Check this fiddle -> https://fiddle.jshell.net/c8tqvy0r/

Comment: U r ri8. But my constraint is not to use Jquery. Anyways Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can write in jquery

```
jQuery('input[type="button"]').hide();
```

or through css you can give

```
input[type="button"]{
  display:none;
}
```

or

```
input[type="button"]{
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: U r ri8. But my constraint is not to use Jquery. Anyways Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
for (element in input_list)
```

use

```
for(var i=0; i < input_list.length; i++){

    input_list[i].style.visibility = "hidden";

}
```